# Is there a discrete initial topology on the set of real numbers?

Tags: general-topology

Consider the real numbers R first as just a set with no structure.  Then consider it as a topological space R* with the usual topology.  The question is: is there a function f from R to R* whose initial topology on R is discrete? I think not, but the proof escapes me.

Comment: There is no such function. Observe that $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual topology has a countable basis, but $\mathbb{R}$ with the discrete topology does not.

Comment: So are you implying that the continuous image of a non second countable space can't be second countable and if so why?

Comment: That's not what I said. (The image of, say, the unique function $\mathbb{R} \to \{ 0 \}$ is certainly second countable, whether or not $\mathbb{R}$ is topologised discretely.) You need to use an explicit description of the initial topology.

Comment: I was well aware of the second countable differences between the two topologies but why this precludes the descrete topology from being initial still evades me?

Comment: Show that if $X$ has the initial topology with respect to a map $f : X \to Y$ and $Y$ has a second-countable topology, then so does $X$.

Comment: PLease, you show it, I was looking for a proof-not a hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $Y$ be a topological space and let $f : X \to Y$ be a map. The initial topology on $X$ with respect to $f : X \to Y$ is the unique topology with the following property:

- A subset $U \subseteq X$ is open if and only if there is an *open* subset $V \subseteq Y$ such that $U = f^{-1} V$.

Thus, if $\mathcal{B}$ is a basis for the topology of $Y$, then $\{ f^{-1} B : B \in \mathcal{B} \}$ is a basis for the initial topology on $X$. In particular, if $Y$ is second-countable, then so is $X$.

Thus, the discrete topology on $\mathbb{R}$ is *not* an initial topology with respect to any map $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, where the codomain is considered with the usual topology.